# Xcode Objc Firebase Database Adding Multiple Childs to a Node

Tags: objective-c, database, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a child and a child node to my firebase database so that my database looks like this:

```
{    
    "users": {
        "user.uid": {
            "userEmail":"blah@gmail.com.com",
            "project1": {
                "projectName":"1700 Broadway"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code appears as follows:

```
//create a root ref
rootRef = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

//create a child of the rootRef
FIRDatabaseReference *usersRef = [rootRef child:@"users"];               

//Create a child under the users ref
FIRDatabaseReference *newUserRef = [usersRef child:user.uid];

//set a value of the dictionary for which UID is the key
[newUserRef setValue:@{@"userEmail":emailString}];

//For some reason this reference isn't being created in FB
//Create a child under the users ref
FIRDatabaseReference *projectRef = [usersRef child:@"project1"];

//set a value of the dictionary for which project1 is the key
[projectRef setValue:@{@"projectName":projectName}];
```

However, my database in firebase is coming out as follows:

```
{    
    "users": {
        "user.uid": {
            "userEmail":"blah@gmail.com.com",
        }
    }
}
```

which looks like this on the console:

```
mastertracker-9cf47addclose
    users
        L0gEKh4f0WctbioRddiziRpfwgC3
            userEmail: "testemail@gmail.com"
```

Can anyone help explain why the "project1" child is not getting referenced under the user id node, which should make the data look like this?

```
mastertracker-9cf47addclose
    users
        L0gEKh4f0WctbioRddiziRpfwgC3
            userEmail: "testemail@gmail.com"
            project1
                projectName: "test project"
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try using `FIRDatabaseReference *projectRef = [newUserRef child:@"project1"];` instead of `FIRDatabaseReference *projectRef = [usersRef child:@"project1"];`

Comment: ^^ worked perfect, thanks @3stud1ant3

Comment: Great, I have added the answer, please accept it if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to add `project1` as sibling to `userEmail` so you should use

```
 FIRDatabaseReference *projectRef = [newUserRef child:@"project1"];
```

instead of

```
FIRDatabaseReference *projectRef = [usersRef child:@"project1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized newUserRef  but not specified key while creating it.
I cannot give code in Objective and I use Swift 3, but your should find a way to specify the key otherwise it generates a location with an auto-calculated key.

```
child("key").set(value).
```